# Dropwizard and validating lists of objects

Tags: java, validation, dropwizard

I have a dropwizard service that accepts a PUT of a JSON document representing a bean. I make use of constraint annotations in the bean implementation and use the @Valid annotation in my Resource method:

```
@PUT
public Response write(@Valid MyBean bean);
```

and everything works rather well.

Now however, I want to pass an **array** of objects in the JSON. I simply changed the method signature to

```
@PUT
public Response write(@Valid List<MyBean> beans);
```

and it generally works, but if there are validation errors then the response is not very user friendly. For example, If I post in 100 beans in the array, and **one** of them is missing a 'name' property, then the response is

```
{"errors":["name may not be empty"]}
```

without any indication of **which** bean in the request has the problem.

Is there a way to overcome this?

Failing that, is there a way for me to obtain a validator in the Resource class so that I can handle all this myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you want this might not be possible. Here is a standalone test of what is happening and how Hibernate wold like for you to hook into it:

```
public class ListBeanValidationTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Bean> asList = Arrays.asList(new Bean("test"), new Bean("test2"));

        Validator v = Validators.newConfiguration().messageInterpolator(new MsgInterpolator()).buildValidatorFactory().getValidator();

        // this is what DW does but i am lazy so you get the main version
        if(asList instanceof Iterable) {
            Iterable values = (Iterable) asList;
            Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = new HashSet<>();
            for(Object value : values) {
                violations.addAll(v.validate(value));
            }

            violations.forEach(System.out::println);
        }
    }

    public static class Bean {

        Bean(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        String name;

        @NotEmpty(message="bean not empty ${name}")
        String wrong;
    }

    public static class MsgInterpolator implements MessageInterpolator {

        @Override
        public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context) {
            return interpolate(messageTemplate, context, Locale.getDefault());
        }

        @Override
        public String interpolate(String messageTemplate, Context context, Locale locale) {
            Object validatedValue = context.getValidatedValue();


            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

The `MessageInterpolator` is the issue here. It does not have an instance of the bean at the time it is interpolating the message for you, so sadly you can not use a reference to that. That means that you will have to do this in another way.

You can obtain a reference to your `validator` (how you do this is up to you, you can find it in the DW environment. I use DI via `Guice` for that).

If you wanted to do this the DW way, you can look into extending: `JacksonMessageBodyProvider` - this is the class that does the validation for DW resources.

I hope that helps

You can also read up on the options of validation that are available to you here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.1/reference/en-US/html/chapter-message-interpolation.html#section-custom-message-interpolation

-- artur

Comment: Thanks - I just ended up doing it myself (not sure why I thought injecting the validator would be tricky)

Comment: I wonder if that would be a good addition. though then again, if your validation message dependent on a different property of the same bean, how do you validate that? You'll get dependency-validation up to where your entire bean is null at which point the message interpolator will NPE while validating which would not be really good. I can imagine that was their  motivation behind not doing this. Also: Hibernate validation does not support lists or arrays by default which is why this may have never been an issue. DW hacks that in themselves :)